# Simplify JavaScript Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Based on an answer I received in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624693/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-javascript-patterns) I would like to know how to *simplify* the following JavaScript pattern.

By simplifying I mean keeping it DRY by not repeating `Module.*method`.

ex.

```
Module.one = function() {
  //one
};
Module.two = function() {
 //two
};
```

This is how I believe it should look like:

Moduje.js

```
var Module = (function(Module) {
  init = function() {
    console.log("init");
  };
  return Module;
})(Module || {});
```

Module.Users.js

```
var Module = Module || {};
Module.Users = (function(Users) {
   init = function() {
    console.log("Module.Users.init");
  };    
  return Module.Users;
})(Module.Users || {});
```

Here is the original code.

Moduje.js

```
var Module = (function(Module) {
  Module.init = function() {
    console.log("init");
  };
  return Module;
})(Module || {});
```

Module.Users.js

```
var Module = Module || {};
Module.Users = (function(Users) {
  Users.init = function() {
    console.log("Module.Users.init");
  };
  return Users;
})(Module.Users || {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well:

```
var Module = (function(Module) {
  init = function() {
    console.log("init");
  };
  return Module;
})(Module || {});
```

No, that won't work.  You're creating the default value for "Module" **outside** that function. You've forgotten `var` in the declaration of "init" too, which in this case sort-of makes it work, but in a broken way (because it's a global variable, if not an error due to "strict" mode possibly being enforced).  Since you're declaring "Module" with that statement, passing "Module" in as a (possible) argument doesn't make any sense.

I don't know what the word "simplify" means to you; the original looks OK to me.

*edit* — if what you'd like to do is get rid of repeated references to the base object, you can use an "extend" function, either from a library or that you write yourself:

```
function extend(target) {
  var sources = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), source;
  for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
    source = sources[i];
    for (var key in source) {
      if (source.hasOwnProperty(key))
        target[key] = source[key];
    }
  }
  return target;
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var Module = createModule(); // make an object however you want

Module = extend(Module, {
  newProperty_1: "hello world",
  newProperty_2: function() {
    // this will become a method on "Module"
  },
  newProperty_3: {
    subObjectProperty: "whatever"
  }
});
```

Comment: Simplify to me means getting rid of repeating Module.method1, Module.method2.